# What are the origins and evolutionary track of the Dominion game?

Tags: dominion, history

Where did Dominion originate from? And how did the game evolve?

I didn't find any source explaining the "origins" or "evolution", rather than just history of Dominion.
[Boardgamegeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/996671/secret-history-dominion) only tells us comments regarding the secret history of Dominion.
Even the [Reddit page](https://www.reddit.com/r/dominion/comments/7fgsfo/see_game_history/)  does not tell uswhere the game originated or how it evolved.

Book and article suggestions would also be helpful.

Comment: Wouldn't its origins and evolution be necessarily part of its history? What are you looking to find out that you have been unable to discover? What do you mean its origins and evolutionary track in particular?

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: Questions stand to get downvoted if they're not clear.

Comment: I didn't downvote or vote-to-close, but I think the first comment sums up the issue that people are having... you said you want origins/evolution "rather than just history", but history IS origins; it isn't clear what the different you mean is. Even my answer, which you accepted, is about the history of Dominion.

Comment: Origin + evolution = history. How a thing started, plus how and why it changed over time is what makes up its history, it sounds like you are asking for the same thing by a different name. It's possible that there is a language barrier here, but you are also unlikely to find any massive information like a book on the history of a not particularly common (compare with poker or monopoly) game.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think you will be able to find an actual published book on the subject, but the creator of Dominion, Donald X Vaccarino, has written multiple articles about the subject. They are published on boardgamegeek.com as well as forum.dominionstrategy.com. The main one is here, entitled "[The Secret History of Dominion](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=8619.0)".

Another post goes through the different cards in the base set and discusses [the history of those cards](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?topic=115.0).

You can find all or most of Donald X's various writings on Dominion history collected in "[The Bible of Donald X.](http://forum.dominionstrategy.com/index.php?board=14.0)". This includes an article for each expansion, discussing the history of the cards in that expansion.